# Why my @singleton doesn't work?

Tags: java, singleton, guice

I met a problem when trying @Singleton of Guice:

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ConfigManager {
    private String data;

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConfigManager config1 = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(ConfigManager.class);
        ConfigManager config2 = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(ConfigManager.class);
        config1.setData("data");
        System.out.println(config2.getData());
    }

}
```

Why this simple sample always print null?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Singletons are global to the injector, not to the JVM. You'll want to tweak your code ever-so-slightly:

```
 Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
 ConfigManager config1 = injector.getInstance(ConfigManager.class);
 ConfigManager config2 = injector.getInstance(ConfigManager.class);
```